# Incoming call notification in Android like whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin

I am an android developer. I didn't get any idea how to show notification when call is generate from server using opentok api. Also if anyone have any idea how **Whatsapp** does it. Kindly share how it will work.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### Add this in your `MANIFEST`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

### Create a high priority notification service

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.util.Objects;

public class HeadsUpNotificationService extends Service {
    private String CHANNEL_ID = "VoipChannel";
    private String CHANNEL_NAME = "Voip Channel";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle data = null;
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            data = intent.getBundleExtra(ConstantApp.FCM_DATA_KEY);
        }
        try {
            Intent receiveCallAction = new Intent(getContext(), HeadsUpNotificationActionReceiver.class);
            receiveCallAction.putExtra(ConstantApp.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY, ConstantApp.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION);
            receiveCallAction.putExtra(ConstantApp.FCM_DATA_KEY, data);
            receiveCallAction.setAction("RECEIVE_CALL");

            Intent cancelCallAction = new Intent(getContext(), HeadsUpNotificationActionReceiver.class);
            cancelCallAction.putExtra(ConstantApp.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY, ConstantApp.CALL_CANCEL_ACTION);
            cancelCallAction.putExtra(ConstantApp.FCM_DATA_KEY, data);
            cancelCallAction.setAction("CANCEL_CALL");

            PendingIntent receiveCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1200, receiveCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            PendingIntent cancelCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1201, cancelCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            createChannel();
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
            if (data != null) {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentText(data.getString("remoteUserName"))
                        .setContentTitle("Incoming Voice Call")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call_green)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_green, "Receive Call", receiveCallPendingIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel_sexy, "Cancel call", cancelCallPendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.voip_ringtone))
                        .setFullScreenIntent(receiveCallPendingIntent, true);
            }

            Notification incomingCallNotification = null;
            if (notificationBuilder != null) {
                incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
            }
            startForeground(120, incomingCallNotification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

/*
Create noticiation channel if OS version is greater than or eqaul to Oreo
*/
    public void createChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Call Notifications");
            channel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.voip_ringtone),
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION).build());
            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

### To handle Notification button clicks

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class HeadsUpNotificationActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra(ConstantApp.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY);
            Bundle data = intent.getBundleExtra(ConstantApp.FCM_DATA_KEY);

            if (action != null) {
                performClickAction(context, action, data);
            }

           // Close the notification after the click action is performed.

            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            context.sendBroadcast(it);
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, HeadsUpNotificationService.class));
        }
    }

    private void performClickAction(Context context, String action, Bundle data) {
        if (action.equals(ConstantApp.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION) && data != null && data.get("type").equals("voip")) {
            Intent openIntent = null;
            try {
                openIntent = new Intent(context, VoiceCallActivity.class));
                openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(openIntent);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (action.equals(ConstantApp.CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION) && data != null && data.get("type").equals("video")) {
            Intent openIntent = null;
            try {
                openIntent = new Intent(context, VideoCallActivity.class));
                openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(openIntent);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (action.equals(ConstantApp.CALL_CANCEL_ACTION)) {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, HeadsUpNotificationService.class));
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            context.sendBroadcast(it);
        }
    }
}
```

[Refer to this post for more details](https://medium.com/@dcostalloyd90/show-incoming-voip-call-notification-and-open-activity-for-android-os-10-5aada2d4c1e4)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rituraj jain. i get an idea but one thing how would i know the calling is comming. Is there any listeners to detect voip is trigger by someone.

Comment: By launching service when FCM notification is received

Comment: The problem is that when app is in background or killed mode then how to would I know the fcm notification is received. One option is notificationListenerService but i don't want this. Is there any other option to listen fcm notification?

Comment: I don't think there is , use a foreground service only!